# opencv: Segmenting a transparent border

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm trying to find the active objects in a game screen like this:

[image]

Where active means that they have the a gray-white border, so here the square in the upper left and the five cards in the middle.

This looked easy at first but the border is translucent and a gradient, so the actual gray value depends a lot on the background and can range from ~180 to 240. Just inRange()'ing all these values produces a lot of noise. Here's a close up of the border for reference:

[image]

So then I tried template matching with one template for each edge, e.g. for the right edge I take a bunch of the black border pixels and the gradient of 4 gray pixels next to it, e.g.

[image]

Then I add threshold on the template matching results and it kinda works:

```
    k = ['right', 'left', 'top', 'bottom']
    mode = cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED
    matches = {}
    addimg = []

    for side in k:
        template = cv2.imread('./img/ab_' + side + '.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        matches[side] = cv2.matchTemplate(im0, template, mode)
        v  = cv2.inRange(matches[side], 0.987, 1)
        #Tools.show(side, v)
        addimg.append(v)

    im1 = sum(addimg)
```

[image]

But it is still finnicky to get the right value for the TM coefficient. Also when the objects are bigger, the border gradient is wider than the gray pixels I use in the template, so the match gets way worse.

So all in all, I think I'm missing a smart algorithm that can match a gradient of varied size and intensity. Any good ideas?

PS there's many more of these screenshots in https://github.com/rc9000/modoscrape/tree/master/img

Comment: I'm not sure where you're heading with this, but you realize that the cards will usually occupy the same coordinates in such a game? you can just work with fixed regions and check if there is a card or not. there is no need to dynamically find the cards on the screen.
and even if you wanted to do that the gradients will be very well defined as they are generated by software. you know beforehand how the software will draw the card boarders

Comment: Unfortunately they can be everywhere, the client size is not fixed, the UI has various moveable parts that can be enlarged or popped out, and the invidual cards are scaled down when there are many. So fixed coordinates are off, as well as stuff subtracting the background.

Comment: each card seems to have a black frame around it. this should make locating the card and determining its size straight forward. once you know the card dimensions you know pretty well how big the "active frame" will be. also the entire card goes pretty dark when inactive. I'd utilize knowledge about the card instead of trying to find good thresholds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's my two cents. This has nothing to do with gradient detection but rather another idea of how to detect these cards.
I take it that your only clue on how to detect the active cards is this border. So sure, you can try and detect the gradient and stuff, but my solution relies on the fact that
a/ the border is clearly seperable (as a component) from the rest of the image with a simple "inRange()" [EDIT after a comment from Piglet : this could also work -and would probably be easier- with working on the black border instead of the gradient] 
b/ the border has a specific shape, and especially a bounding rectangle around it would be straight and have **specific proportions**. I mean since you're always selecting a playing card, its height/width ratio will always be the same.

So my idea is to
1/ threshold
[image]
2/ find components
3/ find bounding rectangles of these components
[image]
4/ select only bounding rectangles which have the specific proportions
[image]

The code follows. It is sort of "quick and dirty", some stuff may be optimized. For example, I'm not checking for rectangle orientation, which is a nice clue. Also, you may have some idea of the card's size even if it can vary from one image to another. Also, you could eliminate rectangles inside other ones, or rectangles significitavely smaller than others...

Take this as "another way" to explore, not a turnkey solution :)

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
import csv

#just converting formats of numpy arrays to pass it from one cv2 function to another.
def convert_for_bounding(coords):
    nb_pts=len(coords[0])
    coordz=np.zeros((nb_pts,2))
    for i in range(nb_pts):
        coordz[i,:]=np.array([int(coords[0][i]),int(coords[1][i])])
    return coordz

#finding width and length of bounding boxes
def find_wid(xs):
    maxx=0
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(i+1,4):
            if abs(xs[i]-xs[j])>=maxx:
                maxx=abs(xs[i]-xs[j])
    return maxx


img=cv2.imread(your image)
orig=np.copy(img)
img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
h,w=img.shape

#thresholding with your "180 - 240" range
img = cv2.inRange(img, 180, 240)

#finding all components
nb_edges, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img, connectivity=8)
size_edges = stats[1:, -1]; nb_edges = nb_edges - 1
contours=[]
for i in range(0, nb_edges):
    #eliminating small components
    if size_edges[i]>=100:
        img2=np.zeros((h,w))
        img2[output == i + 1] = 255
        contours.append(convert_for_bounding(np.nonzero(img2)))



#finding bounding rectangle for each component
for i in range(0,len(contours)):
    c=np.array(contours[i]).astype(int)
    ar=cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(ar)
    box = np.int0([box[:,1],box[:,0]]).T
    xs=box[:,0]
    ys=box[:,1]
    wid=find_wid(xs)
    hei=find_wid(ys)

    #for each rectangle, we'll check if its ratio is like a card one
    card_ratio = 285 / 205
    if hei!=0:
        if hei/wid <=card_ratio*1.05 and hei/wid >= card_ratio*0.95:
            cv2.drawContours(orig, [box], -1, (0,0,255), 2)
```

Result (had to downsize to upload in this answer) :
[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to try this out! I was aleady trying a similar approach with segmenting the black borders and then determining the aspect ratio of the resulting findContours which also wored quite ok: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rc9000/modoscrape/master/img/demo.PNG Probably with applying this to the gray border like you did I could make it working. It is a bit more complicated in real life since some non-card object can be clickable as well, and the objects can stack/overlap on the screen so there the aspect ratio doesn't work

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer in a day or so unless some really good idea for the gradient shows up.

Comment: OK, it seems you indeed need to segment the gradient if you can't have any reliable info on the shape/size of the object to detect. Thanks for the answer acceptance. Maybe try asking on the OpenCV Q&A forum (sort of similar layout than SO) http://www.answers.opencv.org/questions/